# Validate user input from form on the posted ASP page

Tags: javascript, validation, asp-classic

I have a form written in classic ASP (PAGE1) that collects data and posts it to a page (PAGE2).

In the form there are the following fields: 'Please enter your name' and 'Please enter your age'. When the user enters the data and clicks save a script(JS) is run on page 1 to validate the input.

I would also like the validate the input on the page where it has been posted, just in case the user has javascript disabled.

This is currently on the page where the form has been posted:

```
<%
    if age="" then
       age=0
    end if

%>
```

I'm just wondering how to validate that the user has not entered a decimal number for their age.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this, just treat the value as a string and use `InStr()` to check for the existence of a decimal place.

```vb
<%
If Len(age & "") > 0 And IsNumeric(age & "") Then
  'Does the posted data contain a decimal place?
  If InStr(1, age & "", ".") > 0 Then
    'Handle accordingly.
  Else
    age = CLng(age)
  End If
Else
  age = 0
End If
%>
```